# getting the pattern from file

Tags: shell, shell-script, text-processing

I have a text file in the below format. I want to pick one instance each time(line `ABC` to `MNR`) and work on the respective lines and columns.

```
ABC 12 20150911 121 005 001 
BBC AUX BUX 34 70U 1 ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
AXM B 300
HDG D 34 ? ? ? ? ? ? 
XLG H 43 1 003 ? ? ? ? ?
MNR R 05 0 ? 5 ? ? ? ?
ABC 10 20150910 121 005 001 
BBC AUX BUX 34 70U 1 ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
AXM B 500
HDG D 30 ? ? ? ? ? ? 
XLG H 83 1 003 09 ? ? ? ?
MNR R 09 0 ? 5 ? ? ? ?
ABC 12 20150911 121 005 001 
BBC AUX BUX 34 70U 1 ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
AXM B 380
HDG D 34 43 ? ? ? ? ? 
XLG H 22 1 003 ? ? ? ? ?
MNR R 05 0 1 5 ? ? ? ?
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with those lines?

Comment: I am confused of what you mean by one instance. Do you only want the first lines with `ABC` and `MNR` seen?

Comment: @chaos: i want to make some calculations based on the column values per record

Comment: @Elixir of Love: i mean i want to get lines from ABC to MNR, read them to a file, read some column values, do calculations....then to move to the next set of lines between ABC and MNR ....so on

Comment: It sounds like you are asking, "How do I write a computer program?"  Maybe you should try importing the data into a spreadsheet.  If you need to convert it to a CSV, just run it through `sed 's/ /,/g'`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could certainly parse them into, say, an array of hashes, but then what?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @abcs;

while (<>) {
  my ($name, @values) = split ' ';
  if (m/^ABC\s/) {
    push @abcs, { $name => \@values }
  } else {
    $abcs[-1]->{$name} = \@values;
  }
}

use Data::Dumper; warn Dumper \@abcs;
print $abcs[0]{BBC}[3], "\n";
```